# Python and JSON class

Tags: python, xml, json

I am having trouble with JSON, I can not find suitable information.

Firstly, I managed to make the code to create an XML in python, but not JSON.

I wonder how to transform the xml writer class below in order to convert equivalent to JSON Writer Class.

```
from lxml import etree
import re

class XmlWriter:
    # Function create a xml
    def createNode(self,nodeName, parentNode = '', withAttribs = {}, withValue = ''):

        if nodeName != '':
            nodeName = re.sub(r'/', '_', nodeName)
            nodeName = re.sub(r'#','id',nodeName)
            if parentNode == '':
                # Create a parent node
                createdNode = etree.Element(nodeName)
            else:                  
                # Create a child node
                createdNode = etree.SubElement(parentNode, nodeName)

            # Put the Attributs with value    
            if  withAttribs !={}:
                for key,value in withAttribs.items():
                    createdNode.set(key,value)

            # Put the text content of the xml node
            if withValue != '':
                createdNode.text = withValue
            else:
                pass

            return createdNode

    # Print the XML for information
    def printXML(self,nodeName):
        print (etree.tostring(nodeName, pretty_print=True))

    # Save the XML on the file
    def saveXML(self,nodeName,filename):
        if nodeName != '' or filename !='':
            with open(filename, "w") as f:
                f.write(etree.tostring(nodeName, pretty_print=True))
        else:
            return False
```

I try in several research attempting to create an equivalent of a "tree node" for example:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

But how to create a class to get a result if you do bellow example:

```
n1 = CreateNode(name,parent_dependancy,value)...
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

JSON is very different from XML, so it’s not possible to get an *equivalent* “JSON Writer”, as you are using specific XML features (attributes). JSON allows you to replicate an object structure. In respect of Python, JSON simply allows you to encode `dict`s, `list`s and simple scalar values (like `str`, `int` etc.).

If you have such a structure, it’s very simple to get the JSON document from it:

```
>>> import json
>>> obj = {
'string-example' : 'foobar',
'int-example' : 42,
'float-example' : 3.14,
'list-example' : [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 ],
'tuple-example' : ( 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 ),
'dict-example' : { 'key' : 'value', 'key2' : 'value2' } }
>>> json.dumps(obj)
'{"list-example": [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21], "int-example": 42, "string-example": "foobar", "tuple-example": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29], "float-example": 3.14, "dict-example": {"key2": "value2", "key": "value"}}'
```

You can read JSON strings using `json.loads` in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can Pretty Print with JSON dumps.  Like this:

```
print json.dumps( jsonData, indent=2 )
```

It is subtle but the indent=2 says that you want the data to be pretty printed.